# Selectively blocking Youtube URLs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filter, youtube

Is there a way to selectively block Youtube videos? I know the Chrome policy allows me to block URLs.  And I could whitelist URLs.  So, I can do this, for example, in a .reg file, for Windows:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlacklist]
"1"="youtube.com"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLWhitelist]
"1"="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlPdfLr1FSo"
```

This would prevent the user from directly browsing to youtube.com or www.youtube.com.  But, for that one youtube URL, the user can watch the video. Sounds great, except a few problems.

Once the user gets into Youtube given the above URL that is whitelisted, he is free to click on other links.  Or search within the Youtube search interface.  Any of those actions will allow the user to view any other youtube video.  Note that the URL in Chrome does change to reflect the selected video -- and that video/URL is different from the one I whitelisted. But it's not blocked if the user first goes through the whitelisted URL.

If the user attempts to directly type in another URL (aside from the one that is whitelisted) in the Chrome address bar, then it is blocked.  But, navigation within Youtube, after going through the whitelisted URL is not prevented.

Perhaps this is by design.  I can see wanting to allow navigation to a given URL, and then movement within an application without everything breaking, in the case of application that is not a single page app.  But, in my use case this is not what I want; once the user is granted access to a short list of whitelisted videos, they can then watch anything they want (even if not approved).

Is it possible to use a combination of the Chrome policy to blacklist and whitelist URLs and a Chrome Extension? Could a Chrome extension read the whitelisted URLs, and before navigation within Chrome to a second URL, it could check if the URL is whitelisted (and not blacklisted) and then prevent navigation?

Comment: Youtube is a modern [SPA site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so it doesn't use browser navigation, instead it simply replaces the contents and visible URL of the same document by using HTML5 History API. An extension can block HTTP requests of the site by using chrome.webRequest API or by intercepting XMLHttpRequest in page context, but you'll have to specify the list of URLs explicitly as extensions can't read policies.

Comment: Thank you again w0xx0m. After digging around I was coming to the same conclusion about extensions not being able to read policies. Surprisingly there does not seem to be an extension on the Chrome Webstore that denies access to YouTube in general, but allows whitelisting specific videos.  I'll have to do some reading and write my own extension, it seems.

Comment: w0xx0m, I wrote my first ever Chrome extension for this.  Not the prettiest thing, but I think it does the job (assuming you apply appropriate Chrome policies that would prevent users from simply turning off the extension): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-safelist/foimdmmeabkjflioekobhdkogahadpmg

Comment: Ah, I forgot extensions can read one thing from chrome policies -chrome.storage.managed, but you'll have to find all the info yourself, I didn't use it.